# GCC: library linked several times can cause "multiple definition" errors?

Tags: compiling, gcc, toolchain

I have a toolchain generated through Buildroot with which I am trying to compile something statically but the build fails with `gcc` saying something about "multiple definition". Now looking at the command line in question, gcc is executed with an link option there occurs twice, i.e. `gcc -lpthread -lpthread`.

I mentioned this on the Buildroot IRC but I was told that this linking the same library twice shouldn't cause any problems. Is this true and is GCC indeed smart enough and might something else be to blame for why the compilation fails?

Comment: This is correct - GCC is smart enough to realize that the two `-lpthread` options are the same library, and the problem you're seeing is coming from somewhere else. Can you post more of, or the entirety of if it's not insanely huge, the actual error message?

Comment: For ages that linkers have been smart enough to ignore duplicate libraries. I would bet my money one of the include files includes something that is also included in the main files.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Linker has nothing to do with include files. Those deal with multiple inclusion using guard macros, but it's a different story.

Comment: When they do, it already happened to me, but granted it had to do with trying to compile code from other architectures/OSes, and *quite some time ago*. I have read the OP again, and indeed it mentions linking, probably I am wrong, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What are your reasons in favor of static linking anyway? Do you build for a target which doesn't have a dynamic linker? This feels a bit like XY problem.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev: I don't have the sources or exact makefiles for the target and didn't yet manage to compile something dynamically which would run there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments below my question the answer is: **No**, linkers are too smart nowadays, the problem has to be something else.